# Are there any games with more than two characters in Theatrhythm?

Tags: theatrhythm-final-fantasy

When you complete a song in Theathrhythm, there's a Title Character bonus of +30 Rhythmia for each character in your party who is from the same Final Fantasy game as the song. If you unlock a second character from the same game, you can use both, for +60 Rhythmia.

Are there any Final Fantasy games for which you can unlock a third or fourth character from the same game?

Comment: Sounds like there should be. ^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there are two Final Fantasy games which have three characters appear in Theatrhythm:

**Final Fantasy IV:**

- Cecil
- Rydia (green shards)
- Kain (navy shards)

**Final Fantasy VII:**

- Cloud
- Aerith (red shards)
- Sephiroth (black shards)

All other games have two characters, except Dissidia, which has only one character, Cosmos (rainbow shards).

Answer (score 2):

Only Final Fantasy VII has three characters in the game: Cloud, Aerith, and Sephiroth.